# how can I convert video files to nook color format on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: video-conversion, ubuntu-11.04

I need to convert some video files (avi, mpeg etc) to Nook color format. Here is an excerpt from their faq page.

NOOkcolor supports the following video file formats: 3gp, 3g2, mp4, m4v; MPEG-4 Simple Profile up to 854x480; H.263 up to 352x288; H.264 Baseline profile up to 854x480.

I think I can do this using Quicktime and iPhone settings but I want to do this on my Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) will work perfectly for you. It is for the most part my go-to video converter. If you want something different, I have read that [WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/) is also good.

From [Handbrake's Homepage](http://handbrake.fr/):

> **Supported Sources:**
>
> - Any DVD or Bluray-like source: VIDEO_TS folder, DVD image, real DVD or bluray (unencrypted -- removal of copy protection is not supported), and some .VOB, .TS and M2TS files
> - Most any multimedia file it can get libavformat to read and libavcodec to decode.
>
> **Outputs:**
>
> - File format: MP4(M4V) and MKV
> - Video: MPEG-4(ffmpeg), H.264(x264), or Theora(libtheora)
> - Audio: AAC, CoreAudio AAC (OS X Only), MP3, or Vorbis. AC-3 pass-through, DTS pass-thorugh (MKV only)

Answer (score 0):

[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) can most likely do this.

> FFmpeg is a complete, cross-platform
>   solution to record, convert and stream
>   audio and video. It includes
>   libavcodec - the leading audio/video
>   codec library. See the documentation
>   for a complete feature list and the
>   Changelog for recent changes.